# trouble installing with npm install (gulp, browserify)

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, browserify

I'm trying install some items for an IoT program but I'm getting the same errors.
I already have MEAN Stack 0.4.2 already installed and I'm wondering if thats apart of the problem

This is the error I keep getting when I try to install browserify:

```
 npm install -g browserify
 npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to      /usr/local/lib/node_modules
 /usr/local/lib
 └─┬ browserify@12.0.1 
   ├── assert@1.3.0 
   ├─┬ browser-pack@6.0.1 
   │ ├─┬ combine-source-map@0.7.1 
   │ │ ├── convert-source-map@1.1.2 
   │ │ ├── inline-source-map@0.6.1 
   │ │ ├── lodash.memoize@3.0.4 
   │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.4.2 
   │ │   └── amdefine@1.0.0 
   │ └── umd@3.0.1 
   ├── browser-resolve@1.11.0 
   ├─┬ browserify-zlib@0.1.4 
   │ └── pako@0.2.8 
   ├─┬ buffer@3.5.4 
   │ ├── base64-js@0.0.8 
   │ └── ieee754@1.1.6 
   ├─┬ concat-stream@1.5.1 
   │ └── typedarray@0.0.6 
   ├─┬ console-browserify@1.1.0 
   │ └── date-now@0.1.4 
   ├── constants-browserify@1.0.0 
   ├─┬ crypto-browserify@3.11.0 
   │ ├─┬ browserify-cipher@1.0.0 
   │ │ ├─┬ browserify-aes@1.0.5 
   │ │ │ └── buffer-xor@1.0.3 
   │ │ ├─┬ browserify-des@1.0.0 
   │ │ │ └─┬ des.js@1.0.0 
   │ │ │   └── minimalistic-assert@1.0.0 
   │ │ └── evp_bytestokey@1.0.0
```

etc. etc. the tree goes on forever

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "browserify"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
 npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/tacomeat/npm-debug.log
```

does this mean the items in the dir tree are installed with some errors?
or will the program not work without the errors being solved?

the other things I'm trying to install are giving the same error....

How can I fix this?

Comment: also is MEAN Stack a good choice for IoT, Arduino, Raspberry Pi development?

Comment: Are you root? If you are installing things globally you need to be able to write to "/usr/local/lib/node_modules".

You could also run `npm init` in the project root and then `npm install xxx` will install to the project root instead of the `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: use sudo npm install

Comment: thanks fellas I can't believe I didn't catch that...